# Simple Unit Test in C

Tags: c, unit-testing

Simple UnitTest macros utility in C. I decided to make this to be able to more easily organize my tests and I emphasized on readability. Please tell me what you think and if this utility would perform well in big unit tests.

**timer.h**

```c
/* Simple timer macros utility */

#ifndef CMC_TIMER_H
#define CMC_TIMER_H

#include <time.h>

typedef struct timer_s
{
    clock_t start;
    clock_t stop;
    double result;
} timer_t;

#define TIMER_START(timer) \
    timer.start = clock();

#define TIMER_STOP(timer) \
    timer.stop = clock();

#define TIMER_CALC(timer) \
    timer.result = (double)(((timer.stop - timer.start) * 1000.0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

#endif /* CMC_TIMER_H */
```

**test.h**

```c
/**
 * Simple Unit Test Utility
 *
 * CMC_CREATE_UNIT
 *     Create a UnitTest
 *     Parameters:
 *         - UNAME   : UnitTest name (const char *)
 *         - VERBOSE : Print PASSED / FAILED messages if true (bool)
 *         - BODY    : Body containing all tests related to this UnitTest
 *
 * CMC_CREATE_TEST
 *     Create a Test inside a UnitTest.
 *     Parameters:
 *         - TNAME : Test name (const char *)
 *         - BODY  : Block of code containing a specific test
 *     Inside the BODY use the following macros:
 *         - CMC_TEST_PASS
 *             Pass current test.
 *         - CMC_TEST_FAIL
 *             Fail current test.
 *         - CMC_TEST_PASS_ELSE_FAIL
 *             If given expression is true, pass current test, else fail.
 *         - CMC_TEST_ABORT
 *             Abort current unit test and displays error message. All tests
 *             after the abort won't be called.
 *     All of these macros can only be called once per test.
 *
 * CMC_TEST_COLOR
 *      Define this macro to allow colored output.
 */

#ifndef CMC_TEST_H
#define CMC_TEST_H

#include "timer.h"
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef CMC_TEST_COLOR
static const char *cmc_test_color[] = {"\x1b[32m", "\x1b[31m", "\x1b[35m"};
#endif

typedef struct cmc_test_info_s
{
    uintmax_t total;
    uintmax_t passed;
    uintmax_t failed;
    bool aborted;
    bool verbose;
} cmc_test_info;

/* Logging function */
static void cmc_test_log(const char *unit_name, const char *current_test, bool aborted, bool passed)
{
    if (aborted)
    {
#ifdef CMC_TEST_COLOR
        printf("UNIT_TEST %s %sABORTED\x1b[0m AT %s\n",
               unit_name,
               cmc_test_color[2],
               current_test);
#else
        printf("UNIT_TEST %s ABORTED at %s\n", unit_name, current_test);
#endif
    }
    else
    {
#ifdef CMC_TEST_COLOR
        printf("Test from %s %s%7s\x1b[0m %s\n",
               unit_name,
               passed ? cmc_test_color[0] : cmc_test_color[1],
               passed ? "PASSED" : "FAILED",
               current_test);
#else
        printf("Test from %s %7s %s\n", unit_name, passed ? "PASSED" : "FAILED", current_test);
#endif
    }
}

#define CMC_CREATE_UNIT(UNAME, VERBOSE, BODY)                                               \
    void UNAME(void)                                                                        \
    {                                                                                       \
        const char *unit_name = #UNAME;                                                     \
        const char *current_test = NULL;                                                    \
                                                                                            \
        cmc_test_info tinfo = {0};                                                          \
        timer_t timer = {0};                                                                \
                                                                                            \
        tinfo.verbose = VERBOSE;                                                            \
                                                                                            \
        /* Tests */                                                                         \
        TIMER_START(timer);                                                                 \
        BODY;                                                                               \
        TIMER_STOP(timer);                                                                  \
        TIMER_CALC(timer);                                                                  \
                                                                                            \
        unittest_abort:                                                                     \
        if (tinfo.aborted)                                                                  \
        {                                                                                   \
            cmc_test_log(unit_name, current_test, true, false);                             \
        }                                                                                   \
                                                                                            \
        printf("+--------------------------------------------------+\n");                   \
        printf("| Unit Test Report : %-30s|\n", unit_name);                                 \
        printf("|   TOTAL  : %10" PRIuMAX "                            |\n", tinfo.total);  \
        printf("|   PASSED : %10" PRIuMAX "                            |\n", tinfo.passed); \
        printf("|   FAILED : %10" PRIuMAX "                            |\n", tinfo.failed); \
        printf("|                                                  |\n");                   \
        printf("| Total Unit Test Runtime : %9.0f milliseconds |\n", timer.result);         \
        printf("+--------------------------------------------------+\n");                   \
    }

#define CMC_CREATE_TEST(TNAME, BODY) \
    do                               \
    {                                \
        current_test = #TNAME;       \
                                     \
        tinfo.total += 1;            \
                                     \
        BODY;                        \
                                     \
    } while (0);

#define CMC_TEST_PASS()                                         \
    do                                                          \
    {                                                           \
        tinfo.passed += 1;                                      \
        if (tinfo.verbose)                                      \
            cmc_test_log(unit_name, current_test, false, true); \
                                                                \
    } while (0)

#define CMC_TEST_FAIL()                                          \
    do                                                           \
    {                                                            \
        tinfo.failed += 1;                                       \
        if (tinfo.verbose)                                       \
            cmc_test_log(unit_name, current_test, false, false); \
                                                                 \
    } while (0)

#define CMC_TEST_PASS_ELSE_FAIL(EXPRESSION) \
    do                                      \
    {                                       \
        if (EXPRESSION)                     \
            CMC_TEST_PASS();                \
        else                                \
            CMC_TEST_FAIL();                \
                                            \
    } while (0)

#define CMC_TEST_ABORT()      \
    do                        \
    {                         \
                              \
        tinfo.aborted = true; \
        tinfo.total -= 1;     \
        goto unittest_abort;  \
                              \
    } while (0)

#endif /* CMC_TEST_H */
```

**example.c**

```c
#include "test.h"

uintmax_t gcd(uintmax_t p, uintmax_t q)
{
    if (p == 0)
    {
        return q;
    }

    if (q == 0)
    {
        return p;
    }

    uintmax_t r = p % q;

    while (r != 0)
    {
        p = q;
        q = r;
        r = p % q;
    }

    return q;
}

CMC_CREATE_UNIT(gcd_test, true, {

    CMC_CREATE_TEST(edge_cases, {
        uintmax_t r1 = gcd(0, 0);
        uintmax_t r2 = gcd(0, 9);

        CMC_TEST_PASS_ELSE_FAIL(r1 == 0 && r2 == 9);
    })

    CMC_CREATE_TEST(test1, {

        CMC_TEST_PASS_ELSE_FAIL(gcd(42, 56) == 14);
    })

    CMC_CREATE_TEST(test3, {
        CMC_TEST_FAIL();
    })

    CMC_CREATE_TEST(test2, {
        uintmax_t r = gcd(12, 0);

        if (r == 12)
            CMC_TEST_ABORT();
        else
            CMC_TEST_PASS();
    })

    CMC_CREATE_TEST(test4, {

        uintmax_t r1 = gcd(461952, 116298);
        uintmax_t r2 = gcd(7966496, 314080416);

        CMC_TEST_PASS_ELSE_FAIL(r1 + r2 == 50);
    })

})

int main(void)
{
    gcd_test();
    return 0;
}
```

This is part of the C Macro Collections library hosted [here](https://github.com/LeoVen/C-Macro-Collections).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Statement-like macros should normally be wrapped in `do`...`while(0)`.  They should also avoid multiple expansion of arguments.  So instead of

> ```
> #define TIMER_START(timer) \
>     timer.start = clock();
>
> #define TIMER_STOP(timer) \
>     timer.stop = clock();
>
> #define TIMER_CALC(timer) \
>     timer.result = (double)(((timer.stop - timer.start) * 1000.0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
> ```

I'd recommend

```
#define TIMER_START(timer)                      \
    do { (timer).start = clock(); } while (0)

#define TIMER_STOP(timer)                       \
    do { (timer).stop = clock(); } while (0)

#define TIMER_CALC(timer)                               \
    do {                                                \
        struct timer_s* t = &(timer);                   \
        t->result = (double)(t->stop - t->start)        \
            * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;                  \
    } while (0)
```

or (more likely) a set of real functions instead.

(I fixed the cast that was in the wrong place - it's the result of the subtraction that's an integer value that may lose precision when promoted to `double` for the multiplication).

---

`typedef struct timer_s timer_t` collides with a POSIX reserved identifier, so probably worth avoiding.

---

Please don't embed terminal-specific codes like this:

> ```
> static const char *cmc_test_color[] = {"\x1b[32m", "\x1b[31m", "\x1b[35m"};
> ```

That becomes an impenetrable mess (or worse) on terminal types other than the ones you've considered.  It's better to adapt to the actual known terminal type, perhaps using a library such as termcap.

---

It seems strange that `VERBOSE` is a compile-time setting, rather than a run-time parameter here:

```
#define CMC_CREATE_UNIT(UNAME, VERBOSE, BODY)
```

---

One of the statement-like macros has a stray semicolon after its definition:

```
#define CMC_CREATE_TEST(TNAME, BODY) \
    {                                \
    ...                              \
    } while (0);
```

---

`+= 1` is more idiomatically written as `++`:

```
    ++tinfo.total;
```

Similarly, write `-= 1` using `--`.

---

We'd like the unit-test program to exit with success status only if all tests succeeded.  If any fail, we want to know (e.g. to stop the build at that point).  I suggest creating the test function with an `int` return type to support this, and ending with `return tinfo.aborted || tinfo.failed`.

---

The behaviour when `CMC_TEST_ABORT()` is used is strange.  It's the only code that's setting `tinfo.aborted`, so we could move the `if (tinfo.aborted)` block directly into that code.  OTOH, we shouldn't be printing the elapsed time in that case, as we've skipped the `TIMER_STOP(timer);` and `TIMER_CALC(timer);` lines.

---

Finally, I know it's not really up for review, but I couldn't resist making observations on the `gcd()` function used for testing:

There's no need for a specific `p==0` test - the flow without the test already does the right thing (but the `q==0` test *is* required, as it's used as divisor in the `%` operation).

We can reduce duplication, by moving `p % q` into the test:

```
uintmax_t gcd(uintmax_t p, uintmax_t q)
{
    if (q == 0) {
        return p;
    }

    uintmax_t r;
    while ((r = p % q) != 0) {
        p = q;
        q = r;
    }

    return q;
}
```

Comment: Never heard of `do {...} while(0)` in the context of macros. Learnt something new/old again.

Comment: Could you add an example of how to improve `static const char *cmc_test_color[] = {"\x1b[32m", "\x1b[31m", "\x1b[35m"};` with termcap?

Comment: That's not something I ever do from C (I'm generally happy with plain output).  If you're having trouble using termcap/terminfo, then [so] may be a better place to get help.

Comment: *`typedef struct timer_s timer_t` collides with a reserved identifier (all typedef names ending in _t are reserved for future Standard Library use).* I was going to call that one, but I didn't because I didn't find the text in the Standard. Could you quote the specific section, please?

Comment: I was using CPPReference, which cites its sources as C99 section 7.26 and C11 section K.3.1.2.

Comment: The C99 text is: *Typedef names beginning with `int` or `uint` and ending with `_t` may be added to the types defined in the `<stdint.h>` header.*  I found nothing in C11::N1570::K.3.1.2 or in C17::N2176.  POSIX, however, does reserve the suffix `_t` completely: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html

Comment: Oops, yes I misread that.  You're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3):

**- `__func__`**

`__func__` exists for a reason; use it instead of `const char *unit_name = #UNAME;`:

```c
cmc_test_log(__func__, current_test, true, false);
...
printf("| Unit Test Report : %-30s|\n", __func__);
```

---

**- `printf("%s", NULL);`**

Strictly speaking, that is Undefined Behaviour.  glibc has a trick, and prints `(null)` instead, but that trick is very unreliable, because if gcc decides to optimize `printf` into `puts`, then UB is invoked (read more: [*Adding newline character to printf() changes code behaviour* on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/q/45738298)).

So this code is probably invoking UB, given that all arguments are known at compile time, and the format string ends in `\n` (`current_test` was defined here: `const char *current_test = NULL;` (Why `const` and `NULL`???)).

```c
#ifdef CMC_TEST_COLOR
        printf("UNIT_TEST %s %sABORTED\x1b[0m AT %s\n",
                        unit_name,
                        cmc_test_color[2],
                        current_test);
#else
```

---

**- Differentiate `typedef`ed identifiers from variable names**

The easiest thing is to use `_s` for `struct`s (Or just don't `typedef` at all)  (not `_t`; it is reserved by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html)).  You did it once, but forgot to do it in one of the `typedef`s (`cmc_test_info`).

Solution:

```c
struct cmc_test_info_s {
    uintmax_t total;
    uintmax_t passed;
    uintmax_t failed;
    bool aborted;
    bool verbose;
};
typedef struct cmc_test_info_s cmc_test_info_s;
```

---

**- Function-like macros**

Macros that behave like function calls should be named with lowercase to simulate functions, and help differentiate them of other macros that don't behave like functions:

```c
#define timer_calc(timer)   do                              \
{                                                           \
    struct timer_s  *t_ = timer;                            \
    double          diff;                                   \
                                                            \
    diff        = t_->stop - t_->start;                     \
    t_->result  = diff * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;           \
} while (0)

#define CMC_CREATE_UNIT(UNAME, verbose, BODY)               \
void UNAME(void)                                            \
{                                                           \
...
                                                            \
}
```

Variables local to a macro should use names that are unlikely to be used in the calling function to avoid shadowing a variable (Imagine what would happen if the calling function called the macro this way: `timer_calc(t_);`).  The usual convention is to add a trailing underscore to names local to a macro.

---

**- macros that depend on having a local variable with a magic name (source: [Linux Kernel Coding Style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#macros-enums-and-rtl))**

```c
#define FOO(val) bar(index, val)
```

might look like a good thing, but it’s confusing as hell when one reads the code and it’s prone to breakage from seemingly innocent changes.

Easy solution:

```c
#define cmc_test_fail(tinfo, current_test)  do              \
{                                                           \
    struct cmc_test_info_s  tinfo_  = tinfo;                \
                                                            \
    tinfo_.failed++;                                        \
    if (tinfo_.verbose)                                     \
        cmc_test_log(__func__, current_test, false, false); \
                                                            \
} while (0)
```

Comment: For "Why `const` and `NULL`" -- why not? It's not `char* const`, which would be a bit odd but would be a reasonable way to give `NULL` a better, context-specific name. It's `const char*`.

Comment: @NicHartley True, I interpreted it wrongly as `const char *const`. But the question was in the sense that `NULL` is not a valid `current_test` value, and it would be better to give it some valid value, or leave it uninitialized, or ask the user to input a string as a variable. And because of that, I mixed some ideas :)